# How do I search for folders by name in the repository via the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm working on a project where I need to find folders in a specific GitHub repository by their names using the GitHub API. Although I know that the GitHub API allows you to search for files and repositories, I have not found a way to directly search for folders by name.

How can I search for folders by name within a specific repository using the GitHub API? We are interested in any solutions or workarounds, possibly related to analyzing file paths or using specific API requests.

I would appreciate providing code examples or detailed instructions on how this can be implemented.